# (Evil) "General" leader key (SPC) not working in some modes (dired, *Messages*)

Tags: key-bindings, evil, dired

I use Evil, and I'm using [the General package](http://emacsist.com/10779) to set my custom keybindings. I'm using SPC as a leader key. The trouble is, I find that SPC is not interpreted as my leader key in some modes, namely dired, and also in the *Messages* buffer. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

I've defined my leader key like this:

```
(general-define-key
 :states 'motion
 :prefix "SPC"
 ; Bindings under the leader key defined here...
```

Adding `keymaps: 'dired-mode-map` doesn't seem to work, which is odd, because `C-h k SPC` in dired mode shows `SPC runs the command dired-next-line (found in dired-mode-map)...`

Does anyone know how to define my SPC leader key such that it will be effective in all modes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the keybindings in normal state `:states 'normal`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working for me. From https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide - `Remember that binding a key in motion state is like binding a key in the normal, visual, and operator states all at once (unless that key is already bound in one of those states).` 
I've been going through the guide at the above URL but I'm still at a loss, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Did you try adding both `:states 'normal` and `:keymaps 'dired-mode-map`? There is a small distinction between using `:states` and binding in motion state. I believe a key bound in `evil-motion-state-map` would be inherited to normal and insert state keymaps if it is unbound in those. Please read the section **Notes for Evil Users** in https://github.com/noctuid/general.el/blob/master/README.org

Comment: Apparently I hadn't tried that particular combination. It works! Thanks so much, this was driving me nuts!
If I could get my leader key to work in *Messages* (more importantly, in help mode - I discovered it doesn't work there, either) then that would be perfect...

Comment: Try adding `message-buffer-mode-map` to the list of keymaps. Ideally just having `:states 'normal` should enable the keybindings in all modes. I'd check why that's not working, one guess is `SPC` is being rebound somewhere else

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try this, but it doesn't work:
`(general-define-key :keymaps 'messages-buffer-mode-map :states 'normal ...` `C-h m` does suggest that "SPC" is being shadowed. `C-h k SPC` suggest that it's being shadowed by a binding in `evil-motion-state-map`. But `:states 'motion` or `:states '(normal motion)` doesn't work, either.
Interestingly, the situation was similar with help mode (in that `evil-motion-state-map` had a binding for SPC that was shadowing my binding), but in the case of help mode, adding `motion` to `:states` worked for me.

Comment: I can understand why adding `motion` to `:states` would work for `help-mode`, help buffers start in motion state, so binding in motion states would be readily available. Also, there is not need to add global to that list. I am not sure what is not working for you, if you can clarify your comments, I will try to help. PS. if you want a keybinding in all modes, with the particular states just remove `:keymaps`

Comment: I discovered that adding the following code to my .emacs makes the SPC leader key work in \*Messages\*. (switch-to-buffer "*Messages*")
(evil-motion-state)

Answer (score 2):

This what worked for me

As per description. If one does not want keys to be overridden he/she should use `:keymaps ‘override`

```
(general-define-key
 :states 'normal
 :keymaps 'override
 :prefix "SPC"
 ...)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please consider explaining why this works (answers the question) - what it does etc.

Comment: As per [description](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el/tree/1907358fed4ad1ee61fb2a2e1a353b27822a3edd#override-keymaps-and-buffer-local-keybindings). If one does not want keys to be overridden he/she should use `:keymaps ‘override`